# Proof of concept RESTful Python server (using web.py) + testing with cURL

Tags: python, web.py

I am in the process of writing a proof of concept RESTful server using web.py

Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import web
import json


def notfound():
    #return web.notfound("Sorry, the page you were looking for was not found.")
    return json.dumps({'ok':0, 'errcode': 404})

def internalerror():
    #return web.internalerror("Bad, bad server. No donut for you.")
    return json.dumps({'ok':0, 'errcode': 500})


urls = (
    '/(.*)', 'handleRequest',
)


app = web.application(urls, globals())
app.notfound = notfound
app.internalerror = internalerror


class handleRequest:
    def GET(self, method_id):
        if not method_id: 
            return web.notfound()
        else:
            return json.dumps({'ok': method_id})

    def POST(self):
        i = web.input()
        data = web.data() # you can get data use this method
        print data
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I can send GET requests ok, however when I try to send a POST request, I get an internal error. At the moment, I am not sure whether the error is due to cURL not sending the POST correctly (highly unlikely), or whether my server is not correctly implemented (more likely).

This is the command I use to send the POST request:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST -d "value":"30","type":"Tip 3","targetModule":"Target 3","active":true http://localhost:8080/xx/xxx/xxxx
```

Here is the server response:

```
me@localhost:~curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST -d "value":"30","type":"Tip 3","targetModule":"Target 3","active":true http://localhost:8080/xx/xxx/xxxx
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Length: 1382
Content-Type: text/plain

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/web.py-0.36-py2.6.egg/web/wsgiserver/__init__.py", line 1245, in communicate
    req.respond()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/web.py-0.36-py2.6.egg/web/wsgiserver/__init__.py", line 775, in respond
    self.server.gateway(self).respond()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/web.py-0.36-py2.6.egg/web/wsgiserver/__init__.py", line 2018, in respond
    response = self.req.server.wsgi_app(self.env, self.start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/web.py-0.36-py2.6.egg/web/httpserver.py", line 270, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, xstart_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/web.py-0.36-py2.6.egg/web/httpserver.py", line 238, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/web.py-0.36-py2.6.egg/web/application.py", line 277, in wsgi
    result = self.handle_with_processors()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/web.py-0.36-py2.6.egg/web/application.py", line 247, in handle_with_processors
    return process(self.processors)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/web.py-0.36-py2.6.egg/web/application.py", line 244, in process
    raise self.internalerror()
TypeError: exceptions must be old-style classes or derived from BaseException, not str
```

What is the cause of the error - and how may I fix it?

Comment: The message is quite clear on the cause.  It names the file and the line number.   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/web.py-0.36-py2.6.egg/web/application.py", line 244.  It's an error in code you did not write.  You need to talk to the folks maintaining web.py.  Not us.

Comment: Also.  Why is there no `return` in the POST method?

Comment: I think you should return `web.notfound(json.dumps({'ok':0, 'errcode': 404}))` in your notfound function. Similar change is required for `internalerror` function.

Comment: @AnandChitipothu: Thanks!. You're a star :) - your suggestion fixed the error I was getting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few issues here.

```
1) POST takes 2 arguments (like GET), self and the resource (method_id is fine)
2) When you're making a POST request you're setting "Content-Type" and not "Accept"
3) Your JSON isn't in quotes as a string
```

If you change your POST to (self, method_id) the following should work:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"value":"30","type":"Tip 3","targetModule":"Target 3","active":true}' http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

You should also wrap the block in a try/except to catch errors and do something useful with them:

```
def POST(self,method_id):
    try:
        i = web.input()
        data = web.data() # you can get data use this method
        return
    except Error(e):
        print e
```

Comment: Thanks Kirsten!. BTW, I also had to correct my POST method to return a value - as S. Lott suggested. Incidentally, could you please point me to the documentation about the correct way to implementr the POST method?. The docs on the web.py have an example where the only arg to the POST method is self - that's where I got that usage from.